# Add class="active" to active page using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

## Dynamic Header, CSS Class Change To Active USING PHP (dirrectory)

I want the class of the `<li>` tag to change under the active dirrectory...
 now, every guide shows me how to do it when your page equals it, but i want to change
the `<li>` depending on what dirrectory im on

for example:

if say im on
 http://example.com/RESOURCES/code/opensource,
 or 
 http://example.com/RESOURCES/images/clipart
 i want the "RESOURCES" ^^ `<li>` to  be 'class="active"' while the rest display 'class="noactive"'

or if im on
 http://example.com/tutorials/css/flawless-dropdown-menu
 I want the "tutorials" `<li>` to be 'class="active"' while the rest are 'class="noactive"'

---

### URL Setup:

This is my example of how my url's are displayed...

```
http://example.com/tutorials/css/flawless-dropdown-menu
```

^^That URL is the page of a tutorial....under the "tutorials" directory, than under the "CSS" category directory, than the page title (all of these directories are not real and are rewrites from .htaccess) [irrelevant]

---

### Navigation Setup:

```
<ul id="mainnav">
  <li class="noactive"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/tutorials/">Tutorials</a></li>
  <li class="noactive"><a href="/resources/">Resources</a></li>
  <li class="noactive"><a href="/library/">Library</a></li>
  <li class="noactive"><a href="/our-projects/">Our Projects</a></li>
  <li class="noactive"><a href="/community/">Community</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is the part you need to be active always the first segment?

Comment: if you want flexible code, you have to add your real URL after translate via rewrite code. however i suggest to make it using javascript or jquery.

Comment: No, It all depends on what directory im in, regardless if how many layers of dirrectories i am in deep, i just want it to look for what dirrectory im in (first layer)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Figured out the ANSWER...I was over thinking it.

### HTML

```
<ul id="mainnav">
    <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="tutorials") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="resources") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="library") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="our-projects") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="#">Our Projects</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="community") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="#">Community</a></li>
</ul>
```

### PHP

```
<?php 
$directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
$components = explode('/', $path);
$first_part = $components[1];
?>
```

Comment: Worked for me.but PHP code can be modified with this
$first_part = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");

Answer (score 23):

**header.php**

```
$activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
```

**nav.php**

```
<ul>
    <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'index') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'tutorials') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="/tutorials.php">Tutorials</a></li>
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Through PHP you can try -

```
<?php 
// gets the current URI, remove the left / and then everything after the / on the right
$directory = explode('/',ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'));

// loop through each directory, check against the known directories, and add class   
$directories = array("index", "tutorials","resources","library","our-projects","community"); // set home as 'index', but can be changed based of the home uri
foreach ($directories as $folder){
$active[$folder] = ($directory[0] == $folder)? "active":"noactive";
}
?>

<ul>
  <li class="<?php echo $active['index']?>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="<?php echo $active['tutorials']?>"><a href="/tutorials/">Tutorials</a></li>
  <li class="<?php echo $active['resources']?>"><a href="/resources/">Resources</a></li>
  <li class="<?php echo $active['library']?>"><a href="/library/">Library</a></li>
  <li class="<?php echo $active['our-projects']?>"><a href="/our-projects/">Our Projects</a></li>
  <li class="<?php echo $active['community']?>"><a href="/community/">Community</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @RickCalder I disagree, your answer is better.

Comment: Everything works here, besides the url dirrectory being recognized and applied to the code...but the whole, active, noactive class establishing works. Im just not sure why it isn't recognizing directory

Comment: @AlexSarnowski are you saying that `$directory = explode('/',ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'));` is not working? ie on `http://example.com/tutorials/css/flawless-dropdown-menu` that `$directory != tutorials`? Could you echo `$directory` to see what it is set to, compared to the directory you are in? Could it a `case-sensitive` issue?

Comment: I tried to echo it out and it says "Notice :  Array to string conversion in "

Comment: And yes, i'm saying when i'm on http://example.com/tutorials/css/flawless-dropdown-menu , all of the <li> are class="noactive" , when tutorials should be class="active"

Comment: The warning - "Notice : Array to string conversion in " is caused when you try to manipulate a string when it is actually an array. For example if you had `ltrim($_SERVER,'/')`[array], instead of `ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/')`[string]. Try doing `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and see if prints as `ARRAY ...` or as a string. You could also do it with `print_r($directory)` and `print_r($directory[0])` to check if they are correct and match the directory in your url.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps you:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var parts = document.URL.split("/");
    // [http:, empty, your domain, firstfolder]
    var firstFolder = parts[3];

    $("#mainnav li").attr("class", "noactive");
    $("#mainnav a[href='/" + firstFolder + "/']").parent().attr("class", "active");
});
```

Comment: won't this affect all <li> on the page?

Comment: Of course, but as Alex Sarnowski has not set any id on his ul and this is only demo code, I think it's okay to do so ;)

Comment: how could i possibly change it if , id="mainnav"....that was foolish of me to not set an id.

Comment: @AlexSarnowski I changed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to do with jQuery but this works:

```
$url='http://example.com/tutorials/css/flawless-dropdown-menu';//pass the current url here instead of a static string.
$segments = explode ("/",$url);

$menuItems=array('Tutorials','Resources', 'Library', 'Our-Projects','Community');


$menu=array();
foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
if($segments[3]==strtolower($menuItem)){
    $menu[]=('<li class="active"><a href="/'.strtolower($menuItem).'/">'.str_replace("-"," ",$menuItem).'</a></li>');

} else {
    $menu[]=('<li class="no-active"><a href="/'.strtolower($menuItem).'/">'.str_replace("-"," ",$menuItem).'</a></li>');
}
}
foreach ($menu as $item) {
echo $item.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use mysql_fetch defined your row for menu title.
if we take your menu title is MENU in mysql database and you have to put in
  (Home,tutorials,library,resources,our-projects,community)

```
    <?php
//connect your data bass

 include(connection.php');

//get your from ID like www.google?id=1 

 $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "select * from pages where id='$id'";
    $query1 = mysql_query($query);
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query1))
    {
        ?>


<html>
<?php $active= $row['MENU'];?>
<ul>
  <li class="<?php if($active=='Home'){echo 'active';}else{echo'noactive';}?>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if($active=='tutorials'){echo 'active';}else{echo'noactive';}?>"><a href="/tutorials/">Tutorials</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if($active=='resources'){echo 'active';}else{echo'noactive';}?>"><a href="/resources/">Resources</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if($active=='library'){echo 'active';}else{echo'noactive';}?>"><a href="/library/">Library</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if($active=='our-projects'){echo 'active';}else{echo'noactive';}?>"><a href="/our-projects/">Our Projects</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if($active=='community'){echo 'active';}else{echo'noactive';}?>"><a href="/community/">Community</a></li>
</ul>
</html>
<?php };?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take using PHP:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <?php
        // Defines all pages in navigation
        $pages = array(
            'Home'     => 'index.php',
            'Products' => 'products.php',
            'Services' => 'services.php',
            'Contact'  => 'contact.php',
            'About'    => 'about.php'
        );

        // Gets active page URL
        $active = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        
        // Loops through all pages
        foreach ($pages as $title => $url) {
            // Checks if active url is matched and adds active CSS class
            if ($active === $url) {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'" class="nav-link active">'.$title.'</a></li>';
            } 
            // Prints out default style for remaining links
            else {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'" class="nav-link">'.$title.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer will apply if all your pages have a php extension and you want a long messy way. I put the code below on top of every php page giving each page an ID which means all pages will have an ID which is tiresome and boring and hard to track.

```
<?php $page = 1; ?>
```

Now in my header or navigation I used the code below to put the active class. You can also put an else if you want something else.

```
   <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <ul>

      <li class="<?php if($page == 1){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="url" href="index.php">Index</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if($page == 2){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="url" href="single-post.php">Information</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if($page == 3){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="url" href="single-post.php">Wanted</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if($page == 4){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="url" href="single-post.php">Workshop</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if($page == 5){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="url" href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if($page == 6){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="url" href="featured.php">Featured</a></li>
      <li class="<?php if($page == 7){ echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="url" href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

"includes/header.php" - This goes in Top of the File

```
<?php 
$activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$index="";
$nosotros="";
$cursos="";
$contacto="";

switch ($activePage) {
    case 'index.php':
        $index=' class="current"';
        break;
    case 'nosotros.php':
        $nosotros=' class="current"';
        break;
    case 'cursos.php':
        $cursos=' class="current"';
        break;
    case 'contacto.php':
        $contacto=' class="current"';
        break;
    default:

        break;
     }
?>
```

and this goes on the nav section

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        echo '<li'.$index.'><a href="/"><div>Inicio</div></a></li>';
        echo '<li'.$nosotros.'><a href="nosotros"><div>Nosotros</div></a></li>';
        echo '<li'.$cursos.'><a href="cursos"><div>Cursos</div></a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="http://www.redtechacademy.com"><div>Academia</div></a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="https://www.redtechhackingshop.com"><div>Tienda</div></a></li>';
        echo '<li'.$contacto.'><a href="contacto"><div>Contacto</div></a></li>';
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try the following:

<ul class="sub-menu"> 
   <div class="h-10"></div>
   <li class="<?php if ($your_variable=="test") {echo "active"; } 
     else{echo"noactive";}?>">
     <a href="test.php">Test </a>
   </li>
    <li class="<?php if ($your_variable=="test2") {echo "active"; 
      } else {echo"noactive";}?>">
     <a href="test2.php" >Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if ($your_variable=="test3") {echo 
     "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>">
        <a href="test3.php">Test3</a>
    </li>
 </ul>

 **strong PHP text**

 <?php 
  $directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
   $components = explode('/', $path);
   $your_variable = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"); 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can do a simple thing also :

```
<li class="page-scroll <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=="aboutus.php"){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="aboutus.php">About us</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$getUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']; -> www.example.com/home.php

$getFileName = explode('/',$getUrl);

The result of $getFileName Will Be In Array ->[" ","home.php"]

$result = $getFileName[2]; //home.php
```

```
<li class="<?php if ($result=='' || $result == 'index.php') {echo 'active'; }?>"><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php if ($result=='about.php') {echo 'active'; }?>"><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>
<li class="<?php if ($result=='contact.php') {echo 'active'; }?>"><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace for this.

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$active = str_replace('/','', $path);
<ul>
 <li class="nav-item <?php if($active == '' || $active == 'index.php'){echo 'active';}?>">
  <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">HOME</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item <?php if($active == 'about.php'){echo 'active';}?>">
  <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">ABOUT US</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php  $request_uri= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>
<ul>
 <li class="<?php if((strpos($request_uri,"index.html")!==false) || $request_uri=="" || $request_uri=="/"){echo "selected";}?>"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>

                <li class="<?php if((strpos($request_uri,"service")!==false)){echo "selected";}?>"><a href="/services.html">Services</a> </li>
<li class="<?php if((strpos($request_uri,"product")!==false)){echo "selected";}?>"><a href="/products.html">Products</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if((strpos($request_uri,"blog")!==false)){echo "selected";}?>"><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if((strpos($request_uri,"question")!==false)){echo "selected";}?>"><a href="/question-answers.html">Ques & Ans</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if((strpos($request_uri,"career")!==false)){echo "selected";}?>"><a href="/career.html">Career</a></li>
                <li class="<?php if((strpos($request_uri,"about-us")!==false)){echo "selected";}?>"><a href="/about-us.html">About</a></li>

</ul>
```