# Add html div tag based on file name

Tags: php, html, web

Sorry if this is a nooby question, but I have the following problem:
I have some sort of a Documentation as a multiple webpages. I created a basic navigation bar on the left of the screen using a tutorial... To be able to mark the active link every page has its own unique navigation adding it's own link to a specific div class. 
The problem is that if I wanted to add another page to my collection I would have to add the link in every html document.
I know that there is a possibility to include other pages Php code to have one navigation document, but I have no idea on how to achieve that the current page is getting highlighted. 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you asking about making external class/function or how to pass them information about which page is active?

Comment: A little bit of both, but mostly on how to pass the information. I'd prefer Php instead of JScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Grzegor J I found [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336200/add-class-active-to-active-page-using-php)  which pretty much solves my problem. 
Thanks to everyone for trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your navigation on a separate file it is completely possible and is actually preferred.

Use any of the following:

- [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
- [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
- [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)
- [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

So let's say your navigation HTML is located at `nav.php` you would do something like:

```
<html>
  <head><title>My Awesome Website</title></head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
      <?php
      include_once("nav.php");
      ?>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you update your navigation in the future you will only need to update one file (`nav.php`).

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to make a new function please read this:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php
There is full info how to create function.
Pass to function what page is active you can just simply in this way:

```
function menu($active)
{
  echo $active;
}
menu($active);
```

It's hard to say more, because you didn't show us anything, a construction of HTML or PHP. Please read linked above tutorial. I think it will be enough in this stage of PHP learn.