# How to add active class in php pagination

Tags: php

```
$pagLink = "<ul class='pagination'>";  
                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
                    $pagLink .= "<li class=''><a href='manage_claims.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a><li>";  
                }
                echo $pagLink . "</ul>";
```

I want to add active class to current page! please help me out for this small activity! Thanks in advance to all who's reply me and answer my question!

Comment: `if (i == current page) { addCLass }`

Comment: @u_mulder please explain in details

Comment: Explain __what__?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class="active" to active page using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336200/add-class-active-to-active-page-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your currebt page with loop variable then add class according to it.

```
$pagLink = "<ul class='pagination'>";  
$current_page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page'] : 1; //retrive your current page value here
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
    $active_class = "";
    if($i==$current_page)
    {
      $active_class = "active";
    }
    $pagLink .= "<li class='$active_class'><a href='manage_claims.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a><li>";  
}
echo $pagLink . "</ul>";
```